# Is it bad to create constants on every API call or does the compiler optimizes it

Tags: c#, rest

Is it safe to have a constant created everytime an API call is made?
For example, in the below code the is `IsValueInRange` function is used for validation by the `WriteToDataBase` function and the `WriteToDataBase` is called by the API to save the data to the table.

I am curious about the memory implications of having the constants defined in the function `IsValueInRange` over having them defined as a member variables in the class. Which is the better option and Why?

```
private bool IsValueInRange(double val)
{
    const int valMax = 10000000000;
    const int valMin = 10;
    return val >= valMin && val <= valMax;
}
```

```
public void WriteToDataBase(double val)
{
    if(IsValueInRange(val))
    {
        writeToDb(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not look at the generated IL - using ilspy or dotpeek

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakCCpA3oaQ6ZAHYDOALqQJbOcBuAQwA2pALykArAG56jEuRSkAsgAoAlLVmM5OAJwrBQtTILaAvoQsFC8igCFNp7bcWqNdJ9sYsO3XqUMxSRMvZz0DYWMtBiszIA=

Comment: Does this answer your question? [class-level string constants vs method-level string constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237428/class-level-string-constants-vs-method-level-string-constants)

Comment: short answer - it makes no difference, its a style choice

Comment: Just to clarify: you are "creating" a constant in the source code - nothing gets created at run-time because of the const relative to just having the values in line.

Comment: One way to think of `const` things (whether strings or built-in value types) is that when you declare a `const` all you are doing is aliasing a literal value with s symbolic name